# erlang mnesia create table error

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I am trying to create mnesia table from Erlang shell. I got error and the same error for the below syntax copied from mnesia help documents.

```
mnesia:create_table(employee,
    [{attributes, record_info(fields, employee)}]).
```

got the error

> record employee undefined

tried various combinations, getting same error. mnesia already started.

Comment: The record 'employee' must be defined. Did you declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try
`rd(employee, {emp_no, name, salary, sex, phone, room_no}).` in the erlang shell.

> rd(RecordName, RecordDefinition) Defines a record in the shell.
>   RecordName is an atom and RecordDefinition lists the field names and
>   the default values. Usually record definitions are made known to the
>   shell by use of the rr commands described below, but sometimes it is
>   handy to define records on the fly.

Please see this link:http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html

Comment: Thanks @BlackMamba. This worked. Can you please point me to any documentation related to this? Currently i am referring this http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap2.html, i guess this is the official documentation of erlang mnesia.

Comment: @RajanR.G I have modified the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have the record `employee` defined before you can do `record_info` on it. In the shell use can use `rr(FileName).` command which will find all the record definitions in the file and remember them. In a module you would either define the record directly in the module or include a file which contains the record definition.

The reason for having to do this special handling in the shell is that records are purely a compile-time feature so a record definition doesn't really "exist" anywhere.

**EDIT:**
If you want to define the record directly in shell then you can't use the standard `-record(...).` syntax. That is only valid in modules. The shell sees that as a call to the `record/2` function. You need to use the `rd` shell command. It your case it would become:

```
3> rd(employee, {emp_no, name, salary, sex, phone, room_no}).
employee
4> record_info(fields, employee).
[emp_no,name,salary,sex,phone,romm_no]
5>
```

Then `record_info` works. If you already have the record definitions in a file then use the shell `rr(File).` command instead as it is easier. I think.

Comment: Yes, i tried to define the record using '-record(employee, {emp_no,
                   name,
                   salary,
                   sex,
                   phone,
                   room_no}).
' but i got the response 'exception error: undefined shell command record/2'